# How to slide up/down on page navigation in Ionic 3?

Tags: animation, ionic3, slideup

When I navigate from page A to page B, I want to slide in the page B from the bottom upwards.

How can I do this in Ionic 3?

I have now

```
this.navCtrl.push(PageB, 
                  {session: this.session}, 
                  {animate: true, 
                   animation: 'transition', 
                   duration: 500, 
                   direction: 'forward'}
                 );
```

I tried to change the 'forward' in 'up' but that does not do anything.
Currently I am testing in Chrome browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the navController is the wrong choice for this.

Mostly, the use case for sliding a page from bottom to top is when you want to show modal page. This can be done with the ModalController:

```
constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {

}

showModal(): void {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(PageB, options);
    modal.present();
}
```

Comment: Besides from being a wrong choice, do you know if it is possible in Ionic 3? I came across this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions/ but it does not seem to work in the browser. Probably only works on a real device (=> "native")?

Comment: Yes, NativePageTransitions is cordova plugin and will only work an a real device. If your really want to do this, this plugin seems like the right choice. But as I mentioned, "NativeTransitionOptions.direction : up" will have the same effect as creating a model (in my opinion).

Comment: Modals do behave differently than pages do in several contexts (like on large screens), so FWIW, it may make sense to simulate a modal with a page. I'm working on a problem where I want page functionality with a modal look.